# Google Cloud Functions Crashing

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have a function which has a lot of endpoints. Wrapping up, it is a services' central which handles orders and executions of services.

I have it up and running for about 2 months, and I've never seen a function crash.

Today I published a new service and I got this error:

```
7:13:09.314 PM  csa  Function execution took 7150 ms, finished with status: 'crash'
7:13:09.307 PM  csa  { name: 'Invalid_Key', message: 'Invalid API key', toString: [Function: toString] }
7:13:09.302 PM  csa  Uncaught exception
```

I have no idea what is happening. I tried to change my code in many ways and I always get this error.

No google helped me.

Note: everything I do in this new service is made by others. Actually I even tried to just call other service code, the problem seems to be in this endpoint

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the [node-zendesk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-zendesk) library. It didn't throw an error, but crashed the function.

My solution was to validate the e-mail, which was the field giving me errors.